# Perform OrderBy on the results of Apply with Aggregate OData Version 4

Tags: c#, odata, aggregation, odata-v4

Consider I have an odata query like this:

```
Sessions?$apply=filter(SomeColumn eq 1)/groupby((Application/Name), aggregate(TotalLaunchesCount with sum as Total))
```

Sessions and Application entities are linked by ApplicationId. I want to apply orderby on "Total" and get top 5 results as odata query response.

I tried adding `&$top=5` at the end of the above mentioned query. Its says:

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'Total' on type 'Sessions'.

Can anyone tell me if such query is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported. $skip, $top, $orderby are "performed" on result from $apply chain.
In this case query should looks like this:

```
Sessions?$apply=filter(SomeColumn eq 1)
/groupby((Application/Name), aggregate(TotalLaunchesCount with sum as Total))
&$orderby=Total
&$top=5
```

[3.15 Evaluating $apply](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc362428738)