# Odata with where and sum

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, odata

I'm developing asp.Net-Core application. 
I need to make ODATA request that converts to 
SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(GameCount) 
   FROM [GameReportDaily] 
  where [StartTimeUtc]>'2019-05-13 22:00:00.0000000'
```

I can make request

```
/odata/GameReportDaily?$apply=aggregate(gameCount%20with%20sum%20as%20Total)
```

with no filters and it's works fine. Now i need to add filter, but it's not works:

```
/odata/GameReportDaily?$apply=aggregate(gameCount%20with%20sum%20as%20Total1)&$filter=(StartTimeUtc+ge+2019-05-27T18%3A00%3A00.000Z)+and+(StartTimeUtc+le+2019-05-28T18%3A00%3A00.000Z)
```

response:

> "Message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Property or
>   path StartTimeUtc isn't available in the current context. It was
>   removed in earlier transformation.",

How can i make ODATA request like SQL above?

Comment: Switch the order of apply and filter on the URL?

Comment: I've try it: same result

Comment: Last I checked .Net-core was missing a lot of functionality for OData

Comment: now it's works with groupby and with filters, but i don't know how to make it together

Comment: Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925722/perform-orderby-on-the-results-of-apply-with-aggregate-odata-version-4) and [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_The_aggregate_Transformation_1)